# Persistent storage in PHP (Data_Registry class)

Tags: php, expressionengine

I'm using this library: http://code.google.com/p/data-registry/ with an ExpressionEngine system.

I initialize and set data in an EE plugin like this:

```
Data_Registry::init('MYPAGE');
Data_Registry::setPersistence(TRUE,TRUE)->restoreNameSpace();
Data_Registry::set('MYPAGE_DATA',json_encode($data['result']));
Data_Registry::set('MYPAGE_LOGGEDIN',true);
```

If I then log the values with this code, it shows the values correctly.

```
$fp = fopen('login_model.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, "Data:".Data_Registry::init('MYPAGE')->get('MYPAGE_DATA'). "\n");
fwrite($fp, "Loggedin:".Data_Registry::init('MYPAGE')->get('MYPAGE_LOGGEDIN'). "\n");
fclose($fp);
```

However, when trying to retrieve these values in a template using this code:

```
$data     = Data_Registry::init('MYPAGE')->get('MYPAGE_DATA');
$loggedin = Data_Registry::init('MYPAGE')->get('MYPAGE_LOGGEDIN');
$fp       = fopen('login_model.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, "Data:".$data . "\n");
fwrite($fp, "Loggedin:".$loggedin . "\n");
fclose($fp);
```

Both values are blank.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you flushing the data?  Does Data_Registry require you to flush/save the values?  Is the third code box in a different file than the second one?

Comment: No, not flushing explicitly. You can flush/save but it is not required. no, same file, just appended.

Comment: "If global persistence is enabled, all namespaces are loaded automaticly" so I assume you have to Data_Registry::setPersistence(TRUE,TRUE)->restoreNameSpace();
 on the template to? unless you have set it as the default parameter

Comment: That was it, it wasn't clear in the docs that I also had to call session_start() in each template, too. Post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Waygood, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Waygood's comment:

"If global persistence is enabled, all namespaces are loaded automaticly" so I assume you have to Data_Registry::setPersistence(TRUE,TRUE)->restoreNameSpace(); on the template to? unless you have set it as the default parameter